# Entity Framework 6 - Is there any way to get new rowversion from DbContext.SaveChanges()?

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework

```
var ctxLog = new List<string>();
var accountToUpdate = sAccount.ToEntity();

// sAccount is DTO !

ctx.accounts.Attach(accountToUpdate);
ctx.Entry(accountToUpdate).State = EntityState.Modified;

accountToUpdate.dt_stamp = BllUtils.GetServerDateTime(ctx); 

var log = ctxLog;
ctx.Database.Log = s => log.Add(s);
ctx.SaveChanges();
```

In the code above after `SaveChanges()`, `accountToUpdate.rowversion` is still the old one.

Is there a way to get new `rowversion` value without running a new query against DB?

Answer (score 1):

After save changes `ctx.Entry(accountToUpdate).GetDatabaseValues();` and check `accountToUpdate.rowversion` value has changed or not. This might work

Comment: Well... GetDatabaseValues() is a another query against DB, exactly what i am trying to avoid.

Answer (score 1):

In previous versions of EF, i used the `StoreGeneratedPattern` property on the field. This gets the content after the insert/update.
I don't really know if it results in another round trip.
You can find more info on this on this [blog post](http://blog.devart.com/set-identity-and-computed-properties-in-entity-framework-without-triggers.html)